# SSIS - Granting access to Developers

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, package

My current ELT process is done via an SP. I am new to SSIS and trying to replicate this process using SSIS.

I have created a set of extraction packages in visual studio, but my team members cannot access the control / data flows and are unable to save the changes.

In order to allow my developers to access my packages and deploy them, how would I grant them access?

I have tried changing the security settings but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The default setting for SSIS package projects is to encrypt them with your user key. You need to change the setting to either specify no secret values are stored in your packages or protect your project (and every package inside) with a password you can share with your team.

Answer (score 1):

As @Filburt mentioned in comments, this is because the default protection level, which is set at project level.

In Visual Studio you can right click on the Project and select Properties. You will see a section Security :

[image]

and there you can select a different protection level, for example "Do Not Save Sensitive Data" or "Encrypt Sensitive Data With Password", in which case you need to set a password and share it with your team members.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have used encrypt data with password. This has helped me share my packages with the developers. The developers can edit but cant save the package. It gives them a denied error. Even though our profiles are on the same AD with the same access levels. This means each time they save they will have to create a new version. Is this how it supposed to be?

Comment: are the developer adding the package to their own project or are all working on the same VS IS project?

Comment: The dev team are opening up the same sin file using they own VS